# jQuery autocomplete on various data in single textbox

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I have a textbox on which i want to bind multiple autocomplete JSON data. For example, if I type

Name:

the autocomplete data should display names of employees and after a delimeter (, OR ;) suppose I type

Department:

the autocomplete data should display options to select departments, so on and so forth. Any guidance as to how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) jQuery autocomplete plugin. One of its features is, it can get its autocomplete data over AJAX. So it'll call your script (PHP or what have you) on the server and pass the current contents of the autocomplete text field as a parameter. From there, you can do whatever you want. Pick apart their text at whatever delimiter you choose, return whatever are sensible options for autocompletion, etc, etc. It's all in your hands at that point.

Comment: In continuation to my question, is there a way to store the data once received from server via autocomplete. It would be really heavy to fetch data every time from server.

Comment: @Ashish - My point is that doing an Ajax hit for your data source gives you a lot of flexibility in how you interpret the user input. There is a way to pre-cook the data you hand the thing (it takes a JSON object) but you'll have less ability to parse around separators in the input that way. That's the trade-off.